Common component react-datepicker inclusion for React application
I have common react-components like Button, Checkbox, Datepicker etc.,. I am transpiling using the rollup.config.js. For date picker I am using react-datepicker. All these components are used in all the other create-react-app application.
For Datepicker, I am getting the below error,
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `x`.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `x`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80958:21)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80979:19)
...

react-components/CustomDatePicker/CustomDatePicker.jsx
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

export default function CustomDatePicker() {
    return (
        <DatePicker selected={new Date()} onChange={(date) => { }} />
    );
}

react-palyground/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx
import React from 'react';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.module.css';
import { CustomDatePicker } from '[Organization-folder]/oneems-react-components';

export default function DatepickerElement() {

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Datepicker</h1>
            <CustomDatePicker />
        </>
    );
}



index.js
export { default as Datepicker } from "./DatePicker/DatePicker.jsx";

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

import { CustomDatePicker } from '[Organization-folder]/oneems-react-components'; => this is wrong.
You have exported CustomDatePicker as default in other file so use as per below statement.
import CustomDatePicker from '[Organization-folder]/oneems-react-components'


Forgot to include index.js. There DatePicker is default one. I'm sorry I missed the file.
